# PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground do not perform segue

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, segue, pffacebookutils

Hei, the code bellow somehow doesn't work with segue. It returns:

**Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

Code runs in IBAction Button. Then I perform segue without PFFacebookUtils code, it works fine. From that i guess segue can't be called from PFFacebookUtils because it works somehow in background.

**Code:**

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {
                    print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueSignUpWindow", sender: nil)

                } else {
                    print("User logged in through Facebook!")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueSignUpWindow", sender: self)
            } else {
                print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
                self.loginCancelledLabel.alpha = 1
            }
        }
```

I've tried to insert additional code like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")
                self.show(vc, sender: self)
                print("Hello")
```

Or with function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "segueSignUpWindow") {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")
                self.show(vc, sender: self)
                print("Hello")
            }
        }
```

Nothing works. Does anyone has a working solution? My goal is to make segue to another storyboard after sign in or login proceeded.

I've looked to most threads in stackoverflow. Didn't find working solution.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get:

Made trigger **var segueLogin : Bool = false** with initialised value.

When PFFacebookUtils gets needed values for segue, change trigger to true:

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {
                    print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                    self.segueLogin = true

                } else {
                    print("User logged in through Facebook!")
                    self.segueLogin = true
                }
            } else {
                print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
                self.loginCancelledLabel.alpha = 1
            }
        }
```

Then added code to **viewDidAppear** class. Realised it starts everytime PFFacebookUtils complete. So it checks if returned value is true and performs segue after successful PFFacebookUtils session:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if segueLogin == true {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueSingup", sender: self)
        }
    }
```